# How can I manage my assets in hyperledger composer?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

In my hyperledger composer project I have a medicine as an asset. There are different types of medicine, but all medicine need to be approved before they are allowed to be produced and distributed in the supply chain.

Can I store a list of allowed assets in the blockchain, a list which can grow or shrink? Or do I have to store it off-chain?

edit: grammar mistake fixed.

Comment: Create a new asset called `AllowedMedicines` and define an array in it where you can store details about medicines that are allowed. Everytime you try to distribute a medicine, you can refer to the `AllowedMedicines` asset and check if the name is included in the list stored. If you have some code, share it so I can suggest a more detailed approach.

Comment: I don't have the code of this part yet. But that is a really great idea. Really simple. I was perhaps thinking of making an event on which the auditors clients subscribes too. And there, a validation will take place (off-chain) to check if those medicines are allowed. But your idea is easier and validates much earlier. Thank you!

Comment: Another way could be to just define a `Boolean allowed` parameter inside your Medicine asset that can be set to true or false.

Comment: I can't do that, some medicine are allowed to some participants. So there are a lot of variations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your reply to Riccardo Bonesi, I suggest something like this

```
asset AllowedMedicines identified by id {
  o String id
  o Medicines[] medicines
}

concept Medicines {
  o String medicineId
  o String medicineName
  o Participants[] allowedParticipants
}

concept Participants {
  o String participantId // either this is one below
  --> Participant somePerson
  // Any specific meta data you want to store
}
```

Now in your `.js` files you can do something like this

```
const allowedMedicines = await registry.get(id);
const participant; // The person you are checking for
const medicineId; // The medicine against which you are checking
const medicines = allowedMedicines.medicines;
if (medicines.medicineId.contains(medicineId)) {
  // Medicine is in the list;
  let allowedParticipants = medicines.allowedParticipants;
  if (allowedParticipants.contains(participant) {
     // The participant is allowed access to the medicine
  };
};
```

Now of course based on the composer version, some syntax may need to be tweaked, but is the general idea of how you can maintain a mapping.